# flexbox nested panes with parent scroll only

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to work on a sample example where I want to have a scroll bar on the parent pane even if the content of the child panes is more. In the example which I have written I need to have a scroll bar on div with id "khaki" inspite of a seperate scrollbar for each of its child div's with id's "child1" and "child2".

Can any body please try to help me acheive this

Thanks & Regards
sivakiran B

Here is the code.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #main {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    #main div {
      flex-grow: 1;
      overflow: auto;
      min-height: 50px;
      /* this value has been kept here such that even though the content is very less than this the pane will have some heigth other wise due to flex-grow these panes will not enough space because of which scrolling is coming automatically even for small content. Please remove this and check the output once so that we can see the difference */
    }
    
    body {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    #khaki {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      border: 2px dotted black;
    }
    
    #child1 {
      border: 1px solid red;
      background-color: grey;
    }
    
    #child2 {
      border: 1px solid green;
      background-color: violet;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="coral" style="background-color:coral;">white color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite
      colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite color
      white color white color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite
      colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite color white color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite
      colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite
      colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite color white color white color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite
      colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite white color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite
      colorwhite color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite
      colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite color white color white color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite
      colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite color white color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite
      colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite
      colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite color white color white color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite
      colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite</div>
    <div id="lightblue" style="background-color: lightblue; flex-grow:0;" id="myBlueDiv">Hiiiiiiiiiii</div>
    <div id="khaki" style="background-color:khaki;flex-grow:2;">
      This should get background color as khakhiii This should get background color as khakhiii This should get background color as khakhiii This should get background color as khakhiii This should get background color as khakhiii This should get background
      color as khakhiii This should get background color as khakhiii This should get background color as khakhiii This should get background color as khakhiii This should get background color as khakhiii This should get background color as khakhiii This
      should get background color as khakhiii This should get background color as khakhiii

      <div id="child1">
        child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild
        1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child
        1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1
        of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1
        of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild
        1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child
        1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1
        of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1
        of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild
        1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child
        1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1
        of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1
        of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of
        khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child
        1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1
        of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khaki
      </div>
      <div id="child2">
        child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki
        child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child
        2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khakichild 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khakichild 2 of khaki
        child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child
        2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of
        khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khakichild 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki
        child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khakichild 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child
        2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of
        khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki
        child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khakichild 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child
        2 of khakichild 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki
        child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child
        2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khakichild 2 of khaki
        child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khakichild 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child
        2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of
        khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki
        child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khakichild 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child
        2 of khaki child 2 of khakichild 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pink" style="background-color:pink;">pink</div>
    <div id="grey" style="background-color:lightgrey;">light grey</div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      console.log(document.querySelector("body").clientHeight);
    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to work out what you're trying to achieve, but the gist is that you need to set heights if you want elements to have scrollbars. Without limited height the elements will stretch to accommodate content.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #main {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    div {
      flex-grow: 1;
      overflow: auto;
      min-height: 50px;
      /* this value has been kept here such that even though the content is very less than this the pane will have some heigth other wise due to flex-grow these panes will not enough space because of which scrolling is coming automatically even for small content. Please remove this and check the output once so that we can see the difference */
    }
    
    body {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    #khaki {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      border: 2px dotted black;
      height: 200px;
    }
    
    #child1 {
      border: 1px solid red;
      background-color: grey;
      height: 200px;
    }
    
    #child2 {
      border: 1px solid green;
      background-color: violet;
      height: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="coral" style="background-color:coral;">white color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite
      colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite color
      white color white color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite
      colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite color white color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite
      colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite
      colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite color white color white color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite
      colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite white color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite
      colorwhite color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite
      colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite color white color white color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite
      colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite color white color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite
      colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite
      colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite color white color white color white colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite
      colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite colorwhite</div>
    <div id="lightblue" style="background-color: lightblue; flex-grow:0;" id="myBlueDiv">Hiiiiiiiiiii</div>
    <div id="khaki" style="background-color:khaki;flex-grow:2;">
      This should get background color as khakhiii This should get background color as khakhiii This should get background color as khakhiii This should get background color as khakhiii This should get background color as khakhiii This should get background
      color as khakhiii This should get background color as khakhiii This should get background color as khakhiii This should get background color as khakhiii This should get background color as khakhiii This should get background color as khakhiii This
      should get background color as khakhiii This should get background color as khakhiii

      <div id="child1">
        child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild
        1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child
        1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1
        of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1
        of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild
        1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child
        1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1
        of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1
        of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild
        1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child
        1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1
        of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1
        of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of
        khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child
        1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1
        of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khakichild 1 of khakichild 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki child 1 of khaki
        child 1 of khaki
      </div>
      <div id="child2">
        child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki
        child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child
        2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khakichild 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khakichild 2 of khaki
        child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child
        2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of
        khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khakichild 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki
        child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khakichild 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child
        2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of
        khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki
        child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khakichild 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child
        2 of khakichild 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki
        child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child
        2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khakichild 2 of khaki
        child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khakichild 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child
        2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of
        khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki
        child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khakichild 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child
        2 of khaki child 2 of khakichild 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki child 2 of khaki
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pink" style="background-color:pink;">pink</div>
    <div id="grey" style="background-color:lightgrey;">light grey</div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      console.log(document.querySelector("body").clientHeight);
    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```